# Spring Boot RestTemplate Composite Response Empty List

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

So I'm developping some microservices in JAVA using Spring Boot and I'm facing some problems involving the objects I'm using.

So I have a data service which is the DB interface and a scheduling service which will be called by the frontend.
Both work with their own Response and Request objects eventhough at this point they are basically the same.

please ignore that there are no getters and setters in the code below.

Data-Service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class DataServiceResource {

  @GetMapping(...)
  public ResponseEntity<JobDetailsResponse> getJobDetailsSingleDate(@PathVariable("singledate") final String date) {

    ...
    return response;

  }

}
```

JobDetailsResponse

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JobDetailsResponse {

    private Object requestSent;
    private List<Job> jobsFound;
    private boolean hasError;

    private String errorMessage;
    private LocalDateTime dataTimestamp;

}
```

JobDetailsSingleDateRequest

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JobDetailsSingleDateRequest {
    private String dateFrom;
}
```

Scheduling Service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class SchedulingServiceResource {

  ...

  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;


  @GetMapping(...)
  public ResponseEntity<ReportDetailsResponse> getReportDetailsSingleDate(@PathVariable("singledate") final String singledate) {

    ResponseEntity<ReportDetailsResponse> quoteResponse = this.restTemplate.exchange(DATA_SERVICE_JOB_DETAILS_SINGLE_DATE_URL + singledate, HttpMethod.GET,
                null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ReportDetailsResponse>() {});

    ...
    return response;

}
```

ReportDetailsSingleDateRequest

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ReportDetailsSingleDateRequest {
    private String dateFrom;
}
```

ReportDetailsResponse

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ReportDetailsResponse {

    private Object requestSent;
    private List<Job> jobsFound;
    private boolean hasError;

    private String errorMessage;
    private LocalDateTime dataTimestamp;

}
```

So when I go through the `quoteResponse.getBody().getJobsFound()` method to check the data I got from the Data Service My List of jobs is empty. 
I read that If the objects are equal in definition, spring would use reflection to pass the values, but in my case its not woking.

Is there a way to consume the microservice without having to add the data service dependency to the scheduling service?

Sorry for the long post but, until now I haven't found a proper example for my case. All the examples I found work with List as return of the microservice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if it is present on your returned JSON ?

Comment: hi, thanks.
I did invoke the data service via Postman and it does return a list of several Objects.